# Convert List<T> to List<string> generically

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a situation where I am reflecting on a set of properties at runtime. When I get the actual property value out, it's simply of type object but I do a check to confirm that it is a generic List. In my scenario these generic Lists will always contain primitive values of some kind (ints, strings, longs, etc). Is there a simple way to convert whatever type of List it is to a list of strings? Like this:

```
object obj = pi.GetValue(item, null);
Type type = obj.GetType();
if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)) {
    List<string> lstStrings = ???;
}
```

Or do I have to have a big switch statement and cast to the appropriate runtime List type first then convert that to List?

thanks

Comment: Completely rewrote my answer, please try it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Cast the list to a non-generic type.**

`IEnumerable` works well, though you're limited in what methods are available until you turn it in to an `IEnumerable<T>`. Once you have an `IEnumerable<T>` you can use `ToString()` to turn the elements into strings.

```
var list = ((IEnumerable)obj).OfType<object>();
List<string> strings = list.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: I came up with similar solution but found `Cast` method before `OfType`. The difference is that `OfType` does filtering. Since everything is an `object` this works fine. I wonder if it's slightly more runtime overhead? Anyway, checking to see if something is an object is probably highly optimized.

Comment: @MichaelWelch I doubt the filtering is relevant from a performance perspective. I've been burned by misusing Cast() before so I usually stick with OfType() since it has the added bonus of filtering out nulls.

Comment: Thanks for the info on `OfType`. I actually never ran across it before.

Comment: @MichaelWelch No problem. I use it all the time for turning non-generic collections into IEnumerable<T> so I can use other Linq methods on them.

Comment: @Oblivious Sage - Yep, that did it, that's the piece I was missing, getting it from the basic interface into IEnumerable<T> without having to explicitly tell it what T was, thank you

Answer (score 1):

In your if statement cast your obj to IEnumerable. You know that is safe because it is a List. Then you can use Enumerable static methods `Cast` and `Select`.

```
List<String> list = ((IEnumerable)obj).Cast<Object>().Select(x => x.ToString());
```